# Select Distinct multiple columns, count distinct

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, distinct

How do you select distinct, and count of distinct? I have a table:

```
col1    col2
 1       1
 1       0
 0       0
 0       1
 1       1
 0       0
```

And I'm trying to get this:

```
col1    col2    count
 1       1        2
 1       0        1
 0       0        2
 0       1        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `GROUP BY` clause with multiple columns.

```
SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*) FROM Table1
GROUP BY col1, col2
```